# Android Studio creating ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a button on MainActivity which opens SecondActivity. My SecondActivity is  a ***ViewPager***, and I also have 2 fragment classes (*fragment1*, *fragment2*) and 2 fragment xml, each with a TextView inside. I cannot work out how to put the two fragment inside the ViewPage using ***FragmentPagerAdapter*** so i can slide from one fragment to another. Can somebody please show/help me?

mainActivity

```
        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCreateWorkout);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));

        }
```

second_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    //
    //how do i add the two fragments here?
    //if this is even the right place
    //

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>
```

also, are you able to show me how to use *FragmentPagerAdapter* to switch between 2 fragments?

Comment: Check this sample [Using ViewPager for Screen Slides](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)

Answer (score 0):

Dont add the fragments inside de viewpager xml tag, you add the fragments by code.FragmentPagerAdapter handle this. You should follow this tutorial for correct implementation:
[Create Swype Viewa](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html)

The PagerFragmentAdapter should look like this, this adapter handle the fragment creation and switch Fragment:

```
public class DemoCollectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
public DemoCollectionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    Fragment fragment = new DemoObjectFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    // Our object is just an integer :-P
    args.putInt(DemoObjectFragment.ARG_OBJECT, i + 1);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 100;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return "OBJECT " + (position + 1);
}
```

}

Inside getItem method, you create the fragment depending on the value of the index.